# How to create pop up windows on google map clusterer circles

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins

I am using the following google map plugin

[google map clusterer](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-clustering.html)

And it works perfectly(insead of random variable that you see in that link I just read locations from database.)

Now I have been asked the followoing: when a user hover on the clustered area(Not a markers) , by clustered area I mean red or yellow or blue circle , I want a pop up window appears for showing some information . I searched the web a lot but I could not find anything, Is it possible to do this?(I appreciate any help)

Update:

Here is the code that I am using :

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).one('init', function (evt, map) {


        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var temp = mark1;
        var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
        var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
        for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

            var contentString = 'test';


            var $marker = $(this).gmap('addMarker',
                    {
                        'id': i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
                        southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
                        'content': 'm_' + i
                    }).click(function (i) {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                            content: this.content
                        }, this);
                    });
            markers.push($marker); // add to the marker array
        }

        $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));



    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest markerclusterer.js this should work:

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(markerClusterer, 'mouseover', function() {
        console.log('mouse over marker clusterer');
    });
```